# Nppexec Howto pass selected link from npp editor to external browser

Tags: google-chrome, notepad++, external-process, nppexec

is it possible to pass selected text to browser (chrome) from notepad ++?
howto pass not path to TEMP_FILE but content?

```
//—need a correction—
set ChromeRun = C:\Documents and Settings\My\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
set TEMP_FILE = $(SYS.TEMP)\npp_sel.txt
// save current selection as ANSI text file
SEL_SAVETO $(TEMP_FILE) :a
// run Chrome.exe for this file
$(ChromeRun) –-homepage $(TEMP_FILE)
```

could you help me out with this script, please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NppExec can refer directly to a highlighted word(s) using `$(CURRENT_WORD)`.  So you don't need sel_saveto or temporary files.

The snippet below works with Firefox.  You should be able to modify it for Chrome in the obvious way.

In NppExec console window:

```
     `npp_run firefox $(CURRENT_WORD)`,
```

where `$(CURRENT_WORD)` is, for example, a URL (http://google.com) that you have highlighted in the current file in Notepad++.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion about $(CURRENT_WORD) was useful for me in Gnome/LINUX. Now, It works!

`set avant = "C:\Program Files\Avant Browser\avant.exe"
npp_run $(avant) $(CURRENT_WORD)`
Just one note if we deal in Windows, there is standard  **Notepad++** **ALT+F2** doing the same...

Comment: It seems the question have to be closed, as you helped me with this

Comment: @Yurij73, Glad it worked.  If you're happy with it, suggest that you accept the answer.  That will signal that the problem is closed.  An upvote never hurts either ;)